# Easy popups for wordpress?

Tags: javascript, embed

I used a theme that had a great function for popup windows - a pop could be created by adding  "#iframe" to any urllink ie

```
<a href="http://yahoo.com#iframe">click for popup</a>
```

Is there a function I can add to achieve this in any theme?

Second - is there an easy way to do popups containing html instead of a url?

Comment: This is JavaScript. You can get that working in any theme/HTML page. But you must have basic knowledge of HTML/CSS. Check your theme for JavaScript library used.

Comment: If you have more than one question, don't be afraid to ask multiple questions, rather than piling them all into 1. You may even earn more reputation/votes :D

Answer (score 0):

WordPress bundles a [ThickBox](http://codylindley.com/thickbox/) library, which can be queued from its core. However it doesn't quite bother to make external reuse easy (not that it's overly complicated though).

Notably ThickBox is *very old*. Depending on your specific requirements it might be preferable to choose a newer library and ship it with your own code (license permitting, and such).

Answer (score 0):

For html solution you can make a div as popup_container 100% width and height and place your popup div inside it. Make popup_container display:none; and make onClick event in javascript on your link to make it display block.